# How to escape charaters in the title of a marker in a Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, html-encode, marker

Say I have this piece of code:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    title: 'B&#250;fals',
    map: map
});
```

This creates a marker as expected but if I hover the mouse over it I don’t see 'Búfals'
as I would expect (instead I see the html code).

This doesn't make any difference:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    title: unescape('B&#250;fals'),
    map: map
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be an overkill but it works:

```
function decode(txt){
  var sp = document.createElement('span');
  sp.innerHTML = txt;
  return sp.innerHTML;
}

decode('B&#250;fals')
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what Daniel suggested, you could try using the unicode value for the character you're trying to display, in your case it would be `\u09fa`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: myLatlng,
   map: map,
   title: unescape('B%FAfals')
});
```

Comment: @Anthony: It is called Percent Encoding (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). This is a chart of the ASCII characters with this encoding: http://i-technica.com/whitestuff/urlencodechart.html. The JavaScript `unescape()` function returns the ASCII string for the specified encoding value.

Comment: I see. Thanks Daniel. The thing is I can't really use this solution as the string I use is html encoded (not percent encoded). At least I understand why escape didn't work.